# Ubuntu thinks my hdmi sound bar is a monitor

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

I am using Ubuntu Mate 17.10 with a nvidia 1060 card and 384.90 driver.
I plugged a sound bar into the hdmi port and the sound works well, however, ubuntu thinks I have an extra hdmi monitor on the side.
As a workaround I can change ViewPortin,ViewPortOut,Panning setting in the Nvidia X Server settings for the sound bar to 1x1

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Sound devices are typically connected to a TV's HDMI out (or passtrough), not directly to a HDMI out. When connected directly that is to be expected regardless of the OS.